# Must specify valid information for parsing in the string

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, landing-page, microsites

I created a simple `SmartCapture` form with 4 fields, then linked it with a sendable data extension. When trying to test it, I am getting the error:

> Must specify valid information for parsing in the string

All 4 fields are Text fields only. What am I missing here?

Below is the code generated by SFMC:

```
%%[

VAR @de, @de_col, @de_statusCode, @de_statusMsg, @errorCode

SET @de = CreateObject("DataExtensionObject")
SetObjectProperty(@de, "CustomerKey", "2E481938-9D92-41B4-AA0F-9FF255D68820")

IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("FirstName")) THEN
    SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "FirstName")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("FirstName"))
    AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF

IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("LastName")) THEN
    SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "LastName")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("LastName"))
    AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF

IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("Email")) THEN
    SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "Email")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("Email"))
    AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF

IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("SubscriberKey")) THEN
    SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
    SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("SubscriberKey"))
    AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF


SET @de_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@de, @de_statusMsg, @errorCode)

IF @de_statusCode != "OK" THEN
    RaiseError(@de_statusMsg, 0, @de_statusCode, @errorCode)
ENDIF

]%%
```

Comment: Please post some source code.  Otherwise we're all left to guess what the issue could be.  And without some details, it won't serve to help anyone that comes after you.

Comment: Hi Adam, I updated my original question with the code

Comment: What are the required columns in your target Data Extension?

Comment: No required columns .. I made all 4 Nullable

Comment: I got it working.. I marked one column as Primary Key and it worked .. doesn't make complete sense though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's a nullable field/primary key issue.

I set up a test Data Extension -- `TestDataExtension` -- with these fields:

```
Email, EmailAddress, primary key, non-nullable
SubscriberKey, Text (254), nullable
FirstName, Text (50), nullable
LastName, Text (50), nullable
```

The code below successfully inserted a row in the Data Extension.

I prefer doing Update/Adds on DataExtensionObjects and defensively writing out the parameters for debugging.

```
%%[

VAR @deObj, @prop, @de_statusCode, @de_statusMsg, @errorCode
var @FirstName, @LastName, @Email, @SubscriberKey

set @FirstName = RequestParameter("FirstName")
set @LastName = RequestParameter("LastName")
set @Email = RequestParameter("Email")
set @SubscriberKey = RequestParameter("SubscriberKey")

/* for debugging */
outputline(concat("<br>@FirstName: ",@FirstName,""))
outputline(concat("<br>@LastName: ",@LastName,""))
outputline(concat("<br>@Email: ",@Email,""))
outputline(concat("<br>@SubscriberKey: ",@SubscriberKey,""))

SET @deObj = CreateObject("DataExtensionObject")
SetObjectProperty(@deObj, "CustomerKey", "TestDataExtension")

IF NOT empty(@FirstName) THEN
    SET @prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@prop, "Name", "FirstName")
    SetObjectProperty(@prop, "Value", @FirstName)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@deObj, "Properties", @prop)
ENDIF

IF NOT empty(@LastName) THEN
    SET @prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@prop, "Name", "LastName")
    SetObjectProperty(@prop, "Value", @LastName)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@deObj, "Properties", @prop)
ENDIF

IF NOT empty(@email) THEN
    SET @prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@prop, "Name", "Email")
    SetObjectProperty(@prop, "Value", @email)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@deObj, "Properties", @prop)
ENDIF

IF NOT empty(@SubscriberKey) THEN
    SET @prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
    SetObjectProperty(@prop, "Value", @SubscriberKey)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@deObj, "Properties", @prop)
ENDIF

SET @updateOptions = CreateObject("UpdateOptions")
SET @saveOptions = CreateObject("SaveOption")
SetObjectProperty(@saveOptions, "SaveAction", "UpdateAdd")
SetObjectProperty(@saveOptions, "PropertyName", "*")
AddObjectArrayItem(@updateOptions, "SaveOptions", @saveOptions)

var @options
SET @de_statusCode = InvokeUpdate(@deObj, @de_statusMsg, @errorCode, @updateOptions)

outputline(concat("<br>@de_statusCode: ",@de_statusCode,""))
outputline(concat("<br>@de_statusMsg: ",@de_statusMsg,""))
outputline(concat("<br>@errorCode: ",@errorCode,""))


IF @de_statusCode != "OK" THEN
    RaiseError(@de_statusMsg, 0, @de_statusCode, @errorCode)
ENDIF

]%%
```

Comment: Hello Adam, I have another related question .. while storing the data into my data extension, I need to also store the business unit name in one of the fields.. 

Is there some system constant/variable which I can use in the AMPScript to get the business unit name?

Comment: You can configure a default value for a column in your target data extension -- if none is specified.  There are built in personalization strings like `memberid` and others that are available in the email context, but not in the way emails are triggered.